# I would like to pass the value entered into the textbox to a python program

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.7

I wrote this code

```
app = Tk()
app.title('Myapp')
app.geometry('260x100+50+50')

labelText =StringVar()
labelText.set('Insert the version you want to check')
label1 = Label(app, textvar=labelText, height=4)
label1.pack()

stringadacercare = StringVar(None)
lastringa = Entry(app, textvar=stringadacercare)
lastringa.place(x=30, y=40, width=200)


progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(orient=HORIZONTAL, length=260, mode='determinate')
progressbar.pack(side='bottom')
progressbar.start()

app.mainloop()
```

I would like to pass the input taken by the textbox into this program instead of the raw_input so binding it to testV

```
 import csv
 import re
 import os
 testV = raw_input('Insert the version you want to find: ')
 fileobj = csv.reader(open('c:\\paths1.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
 for row in fileobj:

for x in row:
    with open(x) as f:
        for line in f:

            if re.match(testV, line):
                print 'The version match: '+ line
            else:
                print 'wrong version'     
    filesize= os.path.getsize(x)
print 'The file size is :'+ str(filesize) +' bytes';
```

Could anyone help me out?
Thank you in advance!!!!!

Comment: sorry nassio, after looking at your gui I realized my code was not a good idea. I deleted it.

Comment: @ Niall can you plese be more specific? There is not check mark....

Comment: Take a quick peek at http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask .  If you accept answers if gives others more motivation to help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you wan to use the second script as a seperate program?  If you must, you can use the subprocess module to pass a variable as a command line argument.

Setup the GUI to use a button and callback something like this:

```
import subprocess
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

def btnCallback():
    #this is the path to your other script
    cmdpath = '/path/to/test.py'

    #extract the textbox variable
    var = stringadacercare.get()

    progressbar.start()

    #pass the variable to the command line
    proc = subprocess.popen([cmdpath,var])

    #block while the subprocess executes
    proc.wait()

    progressbar.stop()

app = Tk()
app.title('Myapp')
app.geometry('260x100+50+50')

labelText =StringVar()
labelText.set('Insert the version you want to check')
label1 = Label(app, textvar=labelText, height=4)
label1.pack()

stringadacercare = StringVar(None)
lastringa = Entry(app, textvar=stringadacercare)
lastringa.place(x=30, y=40, width=200)

progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(orient=HORIZONTAL, length=260, mode='determinate')
progressbar.pack(side='bottom')

#use a button to execute the subprocess
buttonOK = Button(app,text='GO',command=btnCallback)
buttonOK.pack(side='bottom')

app.mainloop()
```

Restructure your test script to accept command line arguments.  You could also import this into your gui app and call the main function, passing the variable directly.

```
import csv
import re
import os

#need the sys module to get the command line args
import sys

def main(testV):
    fileobj = csv.reader(open('c:\\paths1.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')

    for row in fileobj:
        for x in row:
            with open(x) as f:
                for line in f:
                    if re.match(testV, line):
                        print 'The version match: '+ line
                    else:
                        print 'wrong version'
                        filesize= os.path.getsize(x)
                        print 'The file size is :'+ str(filesize) +' bytes'

if __name__=='__main__':
    #get the first command line argument and pass it to main
    testV = sys.argv[1]
    main(testV)
```

If you want to use the test routine as a module instead of by the command line you can add an import statement for your test module and call it from the button callback.

```
...
import mytestmodule

def btnCallback():
    #extract the textbox variable
    var = stringadacercare.get()

    progressbar.start()

    #call the main function from the test module
    mytestmodule.main(var)

    progressbar.stop()

...
```

Comment: That's great!!!I like the button idea that is a lot better, anyway may you please explain me why should I pass the variable to the command line? and other thing I tring to make an apps for a standard window installation, therefore I'm wondering if your code would work into a standard windows(without python)... Anyway thank you very much!!!!

Comment: You don't have to pass it by the command line. The preferred method would be to use the second routine as a module. I chose to show the command line route since it was the closest to what you had implemented. To use the second routine as a [module](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) you would import it in your GUI script and call the main function, passing the variable directly.

Comment: When you are ready, you can bundle this into a Windows executable with [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)

Comment: I tried what you said however it gives me this error:Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: btnCallback() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)... thank for all your help...

Comment: My mistake, button callbacks take no arguments. Most tkinter events pass an event object to the callbacks. I fixed the code.  BTW [effbot.org](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) is a great Tkinter resource for events, etc.

Comment: wrong version
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
The file size is :25 bytes
wrong version
The file size is :25 bytes
wrong version
The file size is :25 bytes
wrong version
The file size is :25 bytes
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\test1py\mainapp.py", line 26, in btnCallback
    proc.wait()
NameError: global name 'proc' is not defined

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7438/discussion-between-tharen-and-nassio)